# How can I get UTF8 to work correctly using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where the table is encoded as utf8.  I have a value in it that's in Korean.  The characters display fine in the database.  But when they are echoed from the database I get a bunch of question marks.

Here is my code, after the connect and select_db statements:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM english WHERE id = ' . $_GET['dealerID'];
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

What am I doing wrong here?  (Yes, 'english' is the right table).  I tried Michael's suggestion below to encode the table as utf8_general_ci and I get a MySQL error.  Suggestions?  What's the correct name of the character set?

If I run a query in PHPMyAdmin, I get 서울시 서초구 서초1동 1425-10 세중프라자 4층/

Comment: Looks okay (except the SQL injection vulnerability on line 2). What's your webpage/console encoding?

Comment: I tried setting the page with a header command to utf8 and that didn't help.  Right now it's iso-2022-kr

Comment: Just a note.. $_GET['dealerID'] should be wrapped in mysql_real_escape_string to prevent sql injection.

Comment: When you say the characters "display fine in the database", what are you using to view them? mysql command line? gui?  Have you set your page encoding to be utf8? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Good catch, both of you.  I'll do that.

Comment: @shummel7845 update your question with any details ... also, if you figure out what works, post it as an answer... welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Michael, I tried your line of code and it makes all of the non-database Korean into question marks in diamonds and doesn't fix the text from the DB.  I'm using Sequel Pro to view the entry.

Comment: Can you update your question with the results from a 'show create table English;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review [this guide](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/) which talks about UTF8, mysql, and PHP all together.

Summary:

1. make sure the browser knows the page is in utf8

   <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
2. The table in mysql needs to be set for utf8 as well as the string fields within the db

   utf8_general_ci
3. tell php that when it talks to mysql to talk in utf8

   mysqli_set_charset('utf8');

Here are some [more details](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/04/about-using-utf-8-fields-in-mysql/) as well.

Comment: Took a look and I'm not sure that can help me, in that I need to have the encoding of the page in "charset=iso-2022-kr" so that embedded Korean can be displayed.  Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that is the right table encoding.  When I import it, I get #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8_general_ci'

Comment: @shummel7845 You are saying two things that conflict.  Either your strings are in UTF8 format or they are in iso-2022-kr... which is it?  Your code assumes they are in utf8, so I'm not sure why you keep referencing iso-2022-kr.

Comment: Yeah, I realize there is a conflict.  I've tried switching everything on the page to utf8, forgetting for a moment the embedded Korean, and I still get ????.  The page is supposed to be in iso-2022-kr because there is raw Korean text in it and that's the only way the copy displays.  If you make the page utf8 you get ????

Comment: See my comment above about the table character set.

Comment: @shummel7845 please don't take offense at this, but you really need to read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html The page does not have to be in iso-2022-kr to display korean text. UTF8 will work fine for displaying korean text... see charset here for example: http://enzine.tistory.com/entry/%EC%99%9C-%ED%85%8C%EC%8A%A4%ED%84%B0%EC%9D%B8%EA%B0%80

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I changed the index and the include and the text from the database shows fine as does the copy in the include.  Unfortunately, that means I have to change all of the other pages to utf8, though.  Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: I replaced all instances of the the iso-2022-kr with the utf8 and my site turned to garbage characters.  Fortunately, we had a backup with the iso-2022-kr.

Comment: @shummel7845 Again, not to be a jerk, but you are missing what I'm saying ;)  You can't just change the charset of the page, UNLESS the charset IS actually what you are changing it to.  For instance, if your page has HTML written in the iso-2022-kr charset, you can't just change the header at the top to be utf8 and expect it to change the page.  You need to use an editor which will let you save the HTML as utf8.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense.  OK, I'll do that.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @shummel7845 No worries.  I just want to make sure that you understand that the charset declaration is just a declaration. It doesn't change what the data is.  For example, if you have a baloney sandwich and you say "This is a ham and cheese sandwich". It's still baloney :)  You have to convert the baloney into ham and cheese first before it becomes a ham and cheese sandwich.  Just declaring the charset won't do that for you.